# Parsoid: Unexpected Token error and failing to initialize

Tags: config, mediawiki, parsoid

```
mwApis:
    - # This is the only required parameter,
      # the URL of you MediaWiki API endpoint.
      uri: 'http://spgenerations.com/wiki/api.php'
```

On my linux box, I can curl this URL and receive the api data.

Regardless of using the apt-get installation or developer installation (ngm install) both instances give me this error:

```
{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"play.projecttidal.com.KVM","pid":12636,"level":30,"levelPath":"info/service-runner","msg":"master(12636) initializing 2 workers","time":"2019-03-12T03:55:47.504Z","v":0}

{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"play.projecttidal.com.KVM","pid":12645,"level":60,"moduleName":"lib/index.js","levelPath":"fatal/service-runner/worker","msg":"Unexpected token ...","time":"2019-03-12T03:55:47.917Z","v":0}

{"name":"parsoid","hostname":"play.projecttidal.com.KVM","pid":12636,"level":40,"message":"first worker died during startup, continue startup","worker_pid":12645,"exit_code":1,"startup_attempt":1,"levelPath":"warn/service-runner/master","msg":"first worker died during startup, continue startup","time":"2019-03-12T03:55:48.925Z","v":0}
```

For context, the hostname here is incorrect and the domain has been removed.

This is my parsoid config:

```
// Parsoid configuration
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = array(
'url' => 'server.spgenerations.com',
'forwardCookies' => true
);
```

I have tried everything under the hidden voodoo sun to get this thing to work and I'm beyond frustrated. 4 hours spent tinkering with URL links to no avail, so please, if you know anything relating to this error, lend a hand.

Answer (score 1):

Check what Node.JS version you are running with:

```
nodejs --version
```

If it is **4.x**: That's too old for Parsoid. I had the same situation (Debian 9, still such an old Node.JS version in the repositories..). After upgrading to 10.x it ran fine for me.

I used the following guide (see Install using a PPA) to update to a newer Node.JS release: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-debian-9